# How to disable/enable page scroll

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, scroll

I am trying to write a JS code that disables/enables page scroll. Apparently there is an issue within Chrome - the console shows this error

```
Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.
```

Here is my JS code:

```
var keys = [32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40];

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function keydown(e) {
    for (var i = keys.length; i--;) {
        if (e.keyCode === keys[i]) {
            preventDefault(e);
            return;
        }
    }
}

function wheel(e) {
  preventDefault(e);
}

function disable_scroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
  }
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
  document.onkeydown = keydown;
  disable_scroll_mobile();
}

function enable_scroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener) {
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
    }
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = document.onkeydown = null;  
    enable_scroll_mobile();
}

// MOBILE
function disable_scroll_mobile(){
  document.addEventListener('touchmove',preventDefault, false);
}
function enable_scroll_mobile(){
  document.removeEventListener('touchmove',preventDefault, false);
}
```

I tried to solve it using this little fix ↓. I added `{ passive: false }` into the `eventListener`s but it will not help:

```
function disable_scroll() {
      if (window.addEventListener) {
          window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, { passive: false });
      }
      window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
      document.onkeydown = keydown;
      disable_scroll_mobile();
    }

    function enable_scroll() {
        if (window.removeEventListener) {
            window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, { passive: false });
        }
        window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = document.onkeydown = null;  
        enable_scroll_mobile();
    }
```

The codepen is here https://codepen.io/wesleypimentel/full/KpgXJW for testing purposes

Answer (score 1):

on scroll you could provide a style to body as

```
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  }
```

or in plain js

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

on a function call

Comment: @PennyDreadful https://karkipy.github.io/test.html here is the link i used the same code, and the source code 
 https://github.com/karkipy/karkipy.github.io/blob/master/test.html, i tried in on mobile devices and it worked

Comment: @PennyDreadful the problem lies with chrome's simplified view feature which stips js events and css